# How to create a database in Clion using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, database, sfml, clion

I have a already created game and want to include a login system using a real database, no files. The game is written in C++ with SFML in Clion. I am also on Linux Mint.

I am new to this so I am wondering how to go about it. What kind of tools would i use? Hope this question is not to close asking for recommendation. I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use SQLite. You can read about it here - https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html

But if you want "real" SQL database, you can go with MySQL  - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-function-overview.html